# Which is more secure? A function in a helper or in a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am creating an application with the help of codeigniter. People can register and log in to the application. User can view each others profile as well.

I noticed that I am using the functions like getting a username from user id, email from user id...... quite a lot. The common thing I noticed about all these functions is that they all are supplied with a user id as its parameter. All these functions are in the controller.

I was thinking to put all these functions in a helper file. As it is quite easy to call the function from helper file. Since, I am using these functions quite a lot, I can directly use them in views if they are from helper file.

Now my question is, is it safe to put these functions in helper instead of controller from the security point of view ? As these functions directly access the database to get the crucial information from the users table.

I know this question might be regarded as very much to a opinion based. But at the same time, I am trying to get the exact answer whether it is safe or not.

Comment: They're equally secure / insecure. It's your code and you are responsible for how you deal with data. Whether something is in a helper that's accessible via views / controllers is irrelevant for the security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a "secure" standpoint, they're both in your code and not visible by the end user.  From a testing standpoint though, code that accesses your database is best tested when it's isolated from code touching other components like UI (which is generally in the controller). This sort of thing would normally go into the model or model helpers in an MVC pattern.

Comment: I came to a point that these functions should be really in models. As you pointed out that anything related to accessing database should be in models.
And I supposed that these kind of functions are frequently used in site, so I first though was to put it in helper. -- well I was completely wrong. Because as per the principal of MVC, these kind of functions relating to database extraction should be in models really. Appreciate for reminding me.